# iwlist output to list or variables

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to create a php webpage to let users connect to a wireless network. Since "wireless-tools" is the only available option i'm using iwlist to show available wifi networks with the following command:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep 'Cell |Quality|ESSID|Auth|key|IE: IEEE|IE: WPA'
```

This gives me the following output:

```
     Cell 01 - Address: 88:03:55:E8:3A:D0
                Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"VGV7519E83ADB"
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 02 - Address: 88:03:55:E8:3A:D1
                Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:"KPN Fon"
      Cell 03 - Address: 90:5C:44:C5:B8:9D
                Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Doggie"
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 04 - Address: 54:FA:3E:60:F9:B1
                Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"HZN249093067"
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 05 - Address: DC:71:44:FA:1D:17
                Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"UPC244948707"
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 06 - Address: 64:D1:A3:31:D1:6C
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Sitecom31D16A"
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 07 - Address: F8:04:2E:30:84:31
                Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"UPC242176060"
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Because I want to list what type of authentication is used I'm showing encryption, IE: IEEE and IE: WPA to list WEP, WPA1 and WPA2 PSK

Is there a way to save the results in variables like this?

```
Cell 01 (88:03:55:E8:3A:D0, VGV7519E83ADB, WPA, WPA2 PSK, 23/70, -87)
Cell 02 (88:03:55:E8:3A:D1, KPN Fon, WEP, , 23/70, -87)
Cell 03 (90:5C:44:C5:B8:9D, Doggie, WPA, WPA2 PSK,  59/70, -51)
etc...
```

I've tried using AWK (gawk is not available) but no success..

The result of

```
iwlist wlan0 scan

      wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 88:03:55:E8:3A:D1
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:"KPN Fon"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000009e127b7513e
                Extra: Last beacon: 6290ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00074B504E20466F6E
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0017FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 0B0504001C127A
                IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                IE: Unknown: DD8F0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B0001031047001000000000000000030000880355E83ADB1021000B436F72706F726174696F6E1023000B564756373531394B5732321024000930322E30302E3133361042000A413334343030333035311054000800060050F204000110110014576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020084
                IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D10
      Cell 02 - Address: 90:5C:44:C5:B8:9D
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Doggie"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001c683317915
                Extra: Last beacon: 90ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00124368696E6565732052657374617572616E74
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B000700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 0B05040031127A
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D10
                IE: Unknown: DDA70050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010E6825C801DD411B2860188B76881A5BF1021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000952616C696E6B415053100800020000103C0001011049000600372A000120
                IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
      Cell 03 - Address: 54:FA:3E:60:F9:B1
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"HZN249093067"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000144750d9416
                Extra: Last beacon: 170ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000C485A4E323439303933303637
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC0103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B000100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 0B05000027127A
                IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
                IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D10
                IE: Unknown: DDA70050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B2860154FA3E60F9B71021001A43656C656E6F20436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E2C20496E632E1023001743656C656E6F20576972656C65737320415020322E344710240006434C313830301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000C43656C656E6F4150322E3447100800024388103C0001011049000600372A000120
      Cell 04 - Address: 64:D1:A3:31:D1:6C
                Channel:8
                Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Sitecom31D16A"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000bc7aa0889
                Extra: Last beacon: 20750ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000D53697465636F6D333144313641
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 030108
                IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEE1117FFFF0000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1608050500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 0B0502000C127A
                IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
                IE: Unknown: DDDE0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B0001031047001027A9A0BC149D4DD5AB6864D1A331D16A1021001153697465636F6D204575726F70652042561023001F53697465636F6D20576972656C657373204769676162697420526F757465721024001F53697465636F6D20576972656C657373204769676162697420526F757465721042000F574C523430303434333831363239321054000800060050F20400011011001F53697465636F6D20576972656C657373204769676162697420526F7574657210080002228C103C0001011049000600372A000120
      Cell 05 - Address: 88:03:55:E8:3A:D0
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"VGV7519E83ADB"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000009e127b72128
                Extra: Last beacon: 1680ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000D56475637353139453833414442
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0017FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 0B0504001C127A
                IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                IE: Unknown: DD8F0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B0001031047001000000000000000030000880355E83ADB1021000B436F72706F726174696F6E1023000B564756373531394B5732321024000930322E30302E3133361042000A413334343030333035311054000800060050F204000110110014576972656C65737320526F757465722857464129100800020084
                IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D10
```

Comment: Of course but don't show us the output after the egrep, show us the input to the egrep since the egrep won't be necessary if you're using awk for the rest of the solution (which you will be). To help you design the best tool to parse iwslist output, we need to see the iwlist output, not what you get after post-processing it with some other tool.

Comment: Added the full output of iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: You're getting there. Now include the expected output given that input and you'll have something we can start to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switched from `iwlist wlan0 scan` to `iw wlan0 scan` which gives a far cleaner output to work with.
Almost got the results I was aiming for when I stumbled upon a GitHub comment from Djey1301: [29 sept 2016](https://gist.github.com/elecnix/182fa522da5dc7389975)

`iw wlan0 scan | sed -e 's#(on wlan# (on wlan#g' | awk -f scan.awk`

scan.awk:

```
BEGIN {

    printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n","MAC","SSID","freq","signal","sig%","WPA","WPA2","WEP","TKIP","CCMP");

}
$1 == "SSID:" { buf = $2; for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) { buf = buf" "$i } ; e["SSID"] = buf ; next }
NF > 0{
if ($1 == "BSS") {
if( $2 ~ /^[a-z0-9:]{17}$/ ) {
if( e["MAC"] ){
printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",e["MAC"],e["SSID"],e["freq"],e["sig"],e["sig%"],e["WPA"],e["WPA2"],e["WEP"],e["TKIP"],e["CCMP"]);
}
    e["MAC"] = $2;
    e["WPA"] = "n";
    e["WPA2"] = "n";
    e["WEP"] = "n";
    e["TKIP"] = "n";
    e["CCMP"] = "n";
    }
}
if ($1 == "SSID:") {
e["SSID"] = $2;
}
if ($1 == "freq:") {
     e["freq"] = $NF;
}
if ($1 == "signal:") {
     e["sig"] = $2 " " $3;
     e["sig%"] = (60 - ((-$2) - 40)) * 100 / 60;
}
if ($1 == "WPA:") {
     e["WPA"] = "y";
}
if ($1 == "RSN:") {
     e["WPA2"] = "y";
}
if ($1 == "WEP:") {
     e["WEP"] = "y";
}
if ($4 == "CCMP" || $5 == "CCMP") {
     e["CCMP"] = "y";
}
if ($4 == "TKIP" || $5 == "TKIP") {
     e["TKIP"] = "y";
}
}
END {
      printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",e["MAC"],e["SSID"],e["freq"],e["sig"],e["sig%"],e["WPA"],e["WPA2"],e["WEP"],e["TKIP"],e["CCMP"]);
}
```

And the result I'm almost happy with:

```
MAC|SSID|freq|signal|sig%|WPA|WPA2|WEP|TKIP|CCMP
9B:5c:44:c5:b8:92|Chinees|2437|-78.00 dBm|36.6667|y|y|n|y|y
89:03:55:e8:3a:d2|VGV7519E83ADB|2412|-83.00 dBm|28.3333|y|y|n|y|y
89:03:55:e8:3a:2b|KPN|2412|-88.00 dBm|20|n|n|n|n|n
62:d1:a3:31:d1:61|Sitecom31D16A|2452|-89.00 dBm|18.3333|n|y|n|n|y
```

updated with help from [Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff)

Comment: The awk style looks a little bit strange. I visited the link you provided. The original version of this awk script looked better but that's actually a matter of taste. Regarding the `KPN fon` issue: an additional `if` or pattern matching could help to fix this. (Sorry, I don't know the output of `iw wlan0 scan`. Thus, I cannot suggest the actual line of code to add.)

Comment: The (partial)output of iw wlan0 scan:
    `BSS 89:03:55:e8:3a:2b(on wlan0)`
 `TSF: 12441130882601 usec (143d, 23:52:10)`
 `freq: 2412`
 `beacon interval: 100 TUs`
 `capability: ESS ShortSlotTime (0x0401)`
 `signal: -80.00 dBm`
 `last seen: 0 ms ago`
 `Information elements from Probe Response frame:`
 `SSID: KPN Fon`
 `Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 9.0 18.0 36.0 54.0` 
 `DS Parameter set: channel 1`
 `ERP: Barker_Preamble_Mode`
(and then some)

Comment: Could you, please, edit the sample input into your answer (because the missing line endings could become helpful to improve the awk scan rules).

Comment: Done. Very happy you're helping me out here!

Comment: So, it looks like `if ($1 == "SSID:")` then store the rest of line as e["SSID"]. In awk: `$1 == "SSID" { buf = $2; for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) { buf = buf" "$i } ; e["SSID"] = buf ; next }`. This line has to be inserted before the `NF > 0` rule. (I hope there are no typos. I wrote this out of mind without testing.)

Comment: I'm getting an "unexpected token" error on the NF > 0 now. (pasted the code before NF > 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143888/discussion-between-scheff-and-etimm).

Comment: running `iw` gives the following warning at the end: `Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable.` Also, [seems `iwlist` can do more than `iw`](https://lwn.net/Articles/628836/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanations, I started a simple parser in `awk`. Actually, I'm wondering why you excluded `gawk`. (You tagged `linux` also. Do you really have a Linux distribution with *K&R awk* instead of `gawk`?)

However, `gawk` would provide much more convenience but it should be possible without also. Because I have actually `gawk` in my cygwin only I used it with `-c` which should limit it to "traditional awk".

Unfortunately, I didn't understand the logic of your output format fully i.e. how to make these `, WEP,` or `, WPA, WPA2 PSK` pieces. Btw. I believe some settings have been changed in your second sample listing. Thus, I left this part out and show you the rest. Following the concept, it should be easy to add the missing rest on your own.

File `list-wlan.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  #debug = 1
  # states
  cell = "" # current cell
  addr = "" # current address
  name = "" # current name
  qual = "" # current quality
  slvl = "" # current signal level
}

END {
  # flush last cell
  flushCell()
}

/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]+/ { # start of new cell
  # flush previous cell
  flushCell()
  # skip prefix spaces
  sub(/[ ]+/, "") # ; print $0
  # extract cell and address from $0
  sep = index($0, " - Address: ")
  cell = substr($0, 1, sep)
  addr = substr($0, sep + 12)
  # debug
  if (debug) print "cell: "cell" addr: "addr
}

/^[ ]*Quality=/ { # quality/signal level
  # skip prefix spaces
  sub(/[ ]+/, "") # ; print $0
  # extract quality
  match($0, /[0-9/]+/) ; qual = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  # extract signal level
  match($0, /[-0-9]+/) ; slvl = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  # debug
  if (debug) print "qual: "qual" slvl: "slvl
}

/^[ ]*ESSID:/ { # name
  # skip prefix spaces
  sub(/[ ]+/, "") # ; print $0
  # extract name
  match($0, /"[^"]*"/) ; name = substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
  # debug
  if (debug) print "name: '"name"'"
}

function flushCell()
{
  if (cell == "") return # nothing to flush
  printf "%s(%s, %s", cell, addr, name
  ## @todo missing authentification params...
  print ", "qual", "slvl")"
}
```

I've saved your second sample input into a file `wlan.txt` for debugging and demonstration. I did this in bash/cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ awk -c -f list-wlan.awk wlan.txt 
Cell 01 (88:03:55:E8:3A:D1, KPN Fon, 29/70, -81)
Cell 02 (90:5C:44:C5:B8:9D, Doggie, 58/70, -52)
Cell 03 (54:FA:3E:60:F9:B1, HZN249093067, 21/70, -89)
Cell 04 (64:D1:A3:31:D1:6C, Sitecom31D16A, 28/70, -82)
Cell 05 (88:03:55:E8:3A:D0, VGV7519E83ADB, 30/70, -80)

$
```

Note:

The `iwlist` seems to provide the network names (sorry, ESSIDs) quoted. So, this makes me suspicious about escaping: Is there escaping possible? What escaping? (Would be interesting how this is looking when a network is named with non-alphanumeric characters including especially quotes.) This has to be sorted out. In result either a complicated unescaping had to be applied or everything (including the quotes) should be simply used as is...
Currently, the quotes  of the network names are simply removed.

Comment: unfortunately -c is not supported

running awk -f list-wean.awk plan.txt results in the following error:
    awk: bad regex '[0-9': Unmatched [ or [^
the awk version doesn't even support --version or -W version

Comment: As I wrote in the text, I have `gawk` and used `-c` to let it behave like `awk`. About the reg. expressions, I'm not sure. I hoped, the expected reg. expressions will be covered by the `-c` argument also...

Comment: It's really hard to find a manual for (non-gnu) awk with google. I believe I've an ancient text book in the companies office. May be, I can update tomorrow. May be, you try to fiddle with the reg. expressions by yourself in the meantime.

Comment: I'm still a little bit uncertain about your awk: If you have a Linux (as you tagged your question) it should be shipped with GNU awk. However, I found [AWK on OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/awk.1). It does not provide a `-c` option. Sounds like (it could be) you are using this one. (Do you have OS/X?) I looked for REs in this manual. At the first glance, everything looks fine but I didn't dig too deep. Btw. The "ancient text book" was a dead end. It mentions REs only in less detail - no help.

Comment: I'm using OpenWRT on an old device. iwlist is getting me nowhere, switched to `iw wlan0 scan` to get output with less gibberish.